# Azure instance number changes gives wrong status to the java tomcat app

Tags: java, tomcat, azure

The documentation of microsoft says ( http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2011/01/04/responding-to-role-topology-changes/ )
you receive a **changing** and a **changed** event when the instance number is changed.

In real live i see a **changing**, a **changed** and a **stopping** event. After that my java application doesn't run the contextDestroyed, but does run the contextInitialized again.

I don't call the cancel methode on the changing event. So a stopping event is unexpected.

So why does i receive a stopping event? Is this a bug?
And while i received a stopping event the server didn't preform a reboot, but my java app contextInitialized is called again? So why is that?

Any inside is appreciated?

Comment: @bas How many servers do you have in the role when this behavior happens?

Comment: @Igorek When azure scales from 2 to 3 and back from 3 to 2. But i think the number is not important.